# Foreach ($arr as $key => $value): $arr will not always have key => value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that I loop through with a foreach, but not all the slots are filled with a key => value pair.

```
$arr = ['trim', 'required', 'max' => 35];

foreach ($arr as $method => $params) {
    //validation logic
}
```

I think that it skips the slots that have no key => value pair.

How can I still make that work?

I know I can do:

```
$arr = ['trim' => 'trim', 'required' => 'required', 'max' => 35];
```

*just* to make it work.

Is there any alternative? I would like to keep the array structure as is (being able to add non key => value pairs too).

Comment: Every array has a key value pair. If you don't specify a key, a numerical one is assigned automatically.

Comment: Why didn't you just test this? If you'd tried `foreach ($arr as $method => $params) {  echo "$method: $params\n" }` you'd have seen it works as written, and it definitely does *not* skip any array elements.

Comment: [It definitely does not skip any. The other keys are just `0` and `1`](http://codepad.org/dNPg8eZf)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about misinterpreted behavior that doesn't exist

Comment: See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php to learn about arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can keep the array the same structure and use the following code.
There is the only line of code added and this is all it takes!

```
$arr = ['trim', 'required', 'max' => 35];

foreach ($arr as $method => $params) 
{
    if(is_int($method)) $method = $params;    // <<---- this is all it takes
    echo $method .' => '. $params .'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array always has keys. If you didn't specify the key, it's an auto assigned int, starting with 0. If you want these as config options and want to go off the key, you may want to do:

```
$arr = ['trim'=>true, 'required'=>true, 'max' => 35];
```

If you absolutely want to keep it as is, you'll need to check both `$method` and `$param`, since you've decided to set up your structure that way. *cough* don't do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to dynamically call functions?

You could use an empty array for functions with no params, that way $method will ALWAYS be a string, and $params will always be an array. At least then you're clearly defining things and you know what each part of your array is for.

```
$arr = [
    'trim' => [],
    'required' => [],
    'max' => [35],
]
```

I don't really like the approach. I prefer that things be explicit and clearly defined.

It might be worth taking a step back and considering the simplest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Check your keys with `array_keys()` function.

```
$arr = ['trim', 'required', 'max' => 35];

print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

Gives:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => max )
```